# Tkinter throwing a KeyError when trying to change frames

Tags: python, tkinter, keyerror

I'm learning tkinter off of the Sentdex tutorials and I into a problem when trying to change pages. My compiler throws something about a KeyError that it doesn't give whenever I change the button on the start page to change to itself rather than PageOne:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Jason/PycharmProjects/gui/main.py", line 43, in <lambda>
    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
  File "C:/Users/Jason/PycharmProjects/gui/main.py", line 29, in show_frame
    frame = self.frames[cont]
KeyError: <class '__main__.PageOne'>
```

and my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT=("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)

        self.frames[StartPage] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

def qf(param):
    print(param)

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        #command within button cant throw args to funcs. Use lambda to throw those args to the func instead
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        #command within button cant throw args to funcs. Use lambda to throw those args to the func instead
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()


app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button is calling `show_frame(PageOne)`, but you never created an instance of `PageOne`. So, of course, there is no key in `self.frames` that matches that page.

Perhaps you intended to create an instance of `PageOne` in your initial code?

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    frame = PageOne(container, self)
    self.frames[PageOne] = frame
    ...
```

If you don't want to create the page until you need it, you can add that code in `show_frame`. First, you'll need to make `container` an instance variable (ie: `self.container`), then modify `show_frame` to look something like this:

```
def show_frame(self, cont):
    if cont not in self.frames:
        self.frames[cont] = cont(self.container, self)
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains several problems. The key code you have gotten caused by that you didn't mapped `<class '__main__.PageOne'>` to something.

If you change your code like the following, you will have no more key errors.

```
    # .....

    frame = StartPage(container, self)
    frame_ = PageOne(container, self)

    self.frames[StartPage] = frame
    self.frames[PageOne] = frame_

    # ......
```

Here is the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT=("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        frame_ = PageOne(container, self)

        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        self.frames[PageOne] = frame_

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        frame_.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

def qf(param):
    print(param)

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        #command within button cant throw args to funcs. Use lambda to throw those args to the func instead
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        #command within button cant throw args to funcs. Use lambda to throw those args to the func instead
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Start Page",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()


app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```